# Installer (LiveUSB Ubuntu 12.10 ) don't detect windows 8 preinstalled Acer Aspire V3-571G-9686

Tags: installation, dual-boot, acer, windows-8, aspire

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a Acer Aspire V3-571G-9686, this but I've not been able to do it. Becuase the installer do not detect any operative systems previously installed (in my case Windows 8)

Here a list of what I have tried/do:

1- Create a LiveUSB with Ubuntu 12.10

2- Turn off the fast startup option on the Windows power management tool.

3- Change the boot order to 1-> Usb 2->CD/DVD 3-> Windows (Booting or something like that)

4- Put de Flash Drive in and restart.

It recognizes the LiveUSB and i select "Try Ubuntu", it works fine. But when I try to install Ubuntu does not detect the existing W8(**don't show the "install along side**" option).

Among other things i shrink one of the partitions on the hard drive, it looks like this
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d565eexewuqxk64/Sin%20t%C3%ADtulo.png
The last partition seems to be a backup of w8.

the laptop came with a Windows 8 preinstalled and I don't want to lose it.

Acer Aspire V3-571G-9686
Intel Core i7-3632QM / NVIDIA GeForce GT640M / 8GB RAM / 500 GB HDD

Comment: do you have a dynamic hard disk drive?

Comment: mojo706 I do not know if I have it, but I guess because I shrunk a partition through Windows, on my old laptop (w7) did the same with the partition of the hard drive and install a Linux distribution and with no problems. but the difference was that the space was created at the end of the disc.